# How do you monitor PostgreSQL queries?

Tags: postgresql, monitoring

I have an application which uses PostgreSQL. I want to monitor all the queries that the application sends to the database. Is there a way to monitor the queries sent?

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-logging.html#GUC-LOG-STATEMENT

Answer (score 0):

You can point pgAdmin4 at your PostgreSQL server, it has a dashboard you can use. You can then drill down in a session to see the query.

If thats not what you are looking for then I guess a logging solution would be what you need like `pg_stat_statements`.

Comment: How would one log `pg_stat_statements`? I mean - if @Axel wants to monitor _all_ queries, and was going to do that by logging `pg_stat_statements`, how would they do so such that all queries were captured?